# Does Heroku support foreign key and unique constraints?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm considering moving a Rails app to Heroku.

In general I add FK constraints with ON DELETE behavior to all FKs. Up to now I've done this by writing raw SQL to add the constraints, as Rails Migrations don't provide a way to do that.

I also add UNIQUE keys where needed.

Will I still be able to add constraints in this way if I move to Heroku?

Another way to put this question would be, do I get direct access to my DB with Heroku, or am I limited to what I can do in migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute any SQL you want in a migration using `connection.execute`, for example:

```
def up
    connection.execute(%q{
        alter table t add constraint c check (x in ('a', 'b', 'c'))
    })
end
def down
    connection.execute('alter table t drop constraint c')
end
```

You can also use [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) to add proper FK support to your migrations and `schema.rb` if you don't want to manage your FKs through raw SQL.

You can use the `:unique => true` option to `add_index` to get unique constraints/indexes.

I've done all of this and even added functions (both SQL and Pl/pgSQL) and triggers to a dedicated PostgreSQL database at Heroku. I'm not sure how much is supported on the shared databases but unique indexes certainly will be and I'm pretty sure FKs and CHECKs will be available as well.